# Flexbox inside table column using white-space: nowrap

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, ellipsis

My white-space nowrap text inside a flexbox container is overflowing the page as far as it goes.

I seem to have hit a weird edge- case in CSS layout.

I have a table, and inside one column I have a flex container with two columns. The first column contains a select, the second text that needs to stay in one line and end in an ellipsis if its too long (text is dynamic)

To be clear, I have no control over the table html. Only inside the column, I can add HTML.

Overflowing text inside a flexbox seems to be a common problem, but all its normal solutions don't work in my case. What I have tried:

- Add min-width: 0; to flex container
- Add flex-shrink: 0; to flex box with text
- Add flex-grow: 1; to flex box with select
- Lots of smaller stuff (width of container to 100%, ect ect)

That were all the solutions I found on many different stackoverflow articles and for me, nothing worked. It all works perfectly fine if the flex container is outside the table, but again, that's not an option for me.

This will show what I mean clearly:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
    column-gap: 3rem;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<!-- Works perfectly (just a test)-->
<b>This is what i need:</b>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='child select'>
    <select>
      <option>Option 1 is a long option</option>
      <option>Option 2 is shorter</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class='child text'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>

<!-- Overflows page (this needs to actually work) -->
<b>This is where it needs to work (inside table):</b>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <label for="select-id">Description field</label>
      </th>
      <td>
        <div class='container'>
          <div class='child select'>
            <select id='select-id'>
              <option>Option 1 is a long option</option>
              <option>Option 2 is shorter</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class='child text'>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am fine with the solution to only work in the very latest browsers, or even if needed a specific browser.

Comment: `table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;` to the table element ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yeah that works! I'm curious, can you explain why? I'm not the best at CSS

Comment: @TemaniAfif if u want, please post this as an answer. Ill accept it as correct. It was the exact solution i needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a table width will adjust based on its content. You have to update the algorithm using [`table-layout: fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout#values) and also add `width: 100%;` to restrict its width:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
  column-gap: 3rem;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<!-- Works perfectly (just a test)-->
<b>This is what i need:</b>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='child select'>
    <select>
      <option>Option 1 is a long option</option>
      <option>Option 2 is shorter</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class='child text'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>

<!-- Overflows page (this needs to actually work) -->
<b>This is where it needs to work (inside table):</b>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <label for="select-id">Description field</label>
      </th>
      <td>
        <div class='container'>
          <div class='child select'>
            <select id='select-id'>
              <option>Option 1 is a long option</option>
              <option>Option 2 is shorter</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class='child text'>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can kinda of hack this to work by assigning width to `.text` using the `vw` unit.

So for example this is what happens when I simply add `width: 50vw;` to `.text`

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
    column-gap: 3rem;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<!-- Works perfectly (just a test)-->
<b>This is what i need:</b>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='child select'>
    <select>
      <option>Option 1 is a long option</option>
      <option>Option 2 is shorter</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class='child text'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>

<!-- Overflows page (this needs to actually work) -->
<b>This is where it needs to work (inside table):</b>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <label for="select-id">Description field</label>
      </th>
      <td>
        <div class='container'>
          <div class='child select'>
            <select id='select-id'>
              <option>Option 1 is a long option</option>
              <option>Option 2 is shorter</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class='child text'>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah i figured that out already, but its not gonna work. There is a lot of UI around all this and many dynamic elements. It would just mess things up. There is no other way u think?

Comment: Hmm well another way could be if you added this to your CSS: `td {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 80%;
}`

Comment: @SamuëlVisser Or another way could be to set `max-width: 100vw;` to `.container` which might make overall dynamic things work better and give you similar results you are looking for.

Comment: honestly im not happy with either of those solutions but it seems there is no other way. I need to set some sort of explicit width for the container. Too bad 

Comment: @SamuëlVisser Yeah sorry I couldn't help more.  I try to avoid tables at all costs when I develop as there's a lot of these weird cases that happen with them.